# iozone runs fail with “No such file or directory” errors

Tags: linux, filesystems, benchmark, iozone

I want to start using iozone to benchmark an aufs filesystem on a virtual machine on ubuntu.

I tried following the manual to use relevant parameters, but I keep getting a weird error on most runs. 
I wrote this command with "root" user:

```
iozone -R -b bench_u01_test.xls -r 8k -s 1g -l 2 -u 5
```

but iozone output was:

```
iozone -R -b bench_u01_test.xls -r 8k -s 1g -l 2 -u 5         Iozone:
Performance Test of File I/O
              Version $Revision: 3.397 $              Compiled for 64 bit mode.               Build: linux-AMD64 
      Contributors:William Norcott, Don Capps, Isom Crawford, Kirby Collins
                   Al Slater, Scott Rhine, Mike Wisner, Ken Goss
                   Steve Landherr, Brad Smith, Mark Kelly, Dr. Alain CYR,
                   Randy Dunlap, Mark Montague, Dan Million, Gavin Brebner,
                   Jean-Marc Zucconi, Jeff Blomberg, Benny Halevy, Dave Boone,
                   Erik Habbinga, Kris Strecker, Walter Wong, Joshua Root,
                   Fabrice Bacchella, Zhenghua Xue, Qin Li, Darren Sawyer.
                   Ben England.
      Run began: Sun Aug 31 08:26:29 2014
      Excel chart generation enabled  
Record Size 8 KB       File size set to 1048576 KB    
Command line used: iozone -R -b bench_u01_test.xls -r 8k -s 1g -l 2 -u 5
Output is in Kbytes/sec        
Time Resolution = 0.000001 seconds.
Processor cache size set to 1024 Kbytes.      
 Processor cache line size set to 32 bytes.
 File stride size set to 17 * record size.
      Min process = 2         Max process = 5         
Throughput test with 2 processes
      Each process writes a 1048576 Kbyte file in 8 Kbyte records
Error writing block 48922, fd= 3 write: No space left on device
Error writing block 94869, fd= 3 write: No space left on device
      Children see throughput for  2 initial writers  =       0.00 KB/sec
      Parent sees throughput for  2 initial writers   =       0.00 KB/sec
      Min throughput per process                      =       0.00 KB/sec  
      Max throughput
per process                   =       0.00 KB/sec     
Avg throughput per process                    =    0.00 KB/sec 
 Min xfer             =       0.00 KB
Child 0 iozone.DUMMY.0: No such file or directory
Child 1 iozone.DUMMY.1: No such file or directory 
. . .
```

Can anyone please provide some advice on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your command it looks like you were testing the current working directory, and simply ran out of free disk space.  With this command you will need up to 5 Gbytes of free space. 
You have -u 5 ( maximum of five processes ) each will have a file that is 1 GBytes 
in size, from the -s 1g option that you used.  The failure indicates that you only
started with ~1.1 GBbytes of space, and simply ran out.